# How to return post form value and action after perform onclick function in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

In this code I am simply do `if($("#teacherID").val()=='0')` then it show alert which is working fine but after change value of `$("#teacherID").val()` then it not return to form action. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

```
<script>
    $(".paypay").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#teacherID").val()=='0')
        {
            alert("Please select academic partner!");
        }
    });
</script>   
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>mymain/xyz" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');" method = "post">               
    <label class="nexCheckbox">Check
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all">
        <span class="checkmark checkmark-action-layout"></span>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary etsfilertButton disabled paypay" name="Pay" value="Pay" disabled>
</form>
```

Thank You

Comment: what has this to do with php?

Comment: Actually I tried `this` but its not work for me @treyBake

Comment: Any answer @treyBake

Comment: `this` is a javascript keyword - (well it's a generic keyword in most languages) - but my question is what has this JavaScript code got to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `e.preventDefault()`, it will not submit the form on its own - you prevent that behavior. You can find the form and submit it after the checks are done.

```
<script>
    $(".paypay").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($("#teacherID").val() == '0') {
            alert("Please select academic partner!");
            return;
        }

        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it works @Qirel but action link inside action show blank page.

Comment: That's another question entirely. But its probably because you're not outputting anything there? Wild guess.